Next.js is bypassing server action calls
When I invoke multiple server actions, some of them take longer due to retrieving large datasets.

While reloading, the drag and drop functionality for widgets is not triggered until all server actions are completed and loading indicators are removed. The drag and drop widget is implemented as a server action and I am using async/await. It seems that during the loading phase, calls related to the drag and drop function are being skipped.
const moveColumn = async (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        const dragColumn = widgets[dragIndex];
        const newColumns = [...widgets];
        newColumns.splice(dragIndex, 1);
        newColumns.splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragColumn);

        const getItems = localStorage.getItem("widgetSettings");
        const settingDoc = JSON.parse(getItems);
        const updatedSettings = {
            ...settingDoc,
            widgets: newColumns
        };

        setWidgets(newColumns);

        localStorage.setItem("widgetSettings", JSON.stringify(updatedSettings));
        debugger;
        updateUserSettings(updatedSettings).then(() => {
            debugger;
            setLoading(false);
        });
        debugger;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

The console before the updateUserSettings is working but the console after updateUserSettings is not working. If I will use the then block then both work but the updateUserSettings is not calling in both of the cases.
I applied the debugger, but it's not entering the debugger block within the then function.


Have you tried wrapping everything in moveColumn with a try..catch? Does the catch block ever enter?

Yes, I am wrapping the drag and drop functionality, but it's not generating any errors.

Can you show what updateUserSettings does?

This is the code for updateUserSettings https://ibb.co/qsxMkB7
Even if I call it with an empty function containing just one console statement, it still does not work.

Well you are calling updateUserSettings, so it should definitely enter. Add debugger into your updateUserSettings function -- does it enter?

Yeah, I added it https://ibb.co/6gNjqRW but not working. While widgets are loading, if all of the widgets complete the loading then it's working.

"not working. While widgets are loading" -- what does that mean? You're passing updatedSettings to updateUserSettings. And updatedSettings already has widgets

Even if I do not pass and receive any arguments into the updateUserSettings then Its behaves exactly the same. Its not have any relation with updatedSettings.

Even when I attempt to call a simple function from the server, it doesn't work while other widgets are loading. I suspect this might be due to some limitations in Next.js's server-side rendering capabilities.

Have you considered using the nextjs debugger with vscode  instead of debugger; (not sure which IDE you are using)? It once helped me figure out code flow easily than debugger.

@AlajedeSamson, I found this issue in the Next.js GitHub repo. It's still open https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50743

Going through the github link shared, making several api call will only work up to a certain threshold.  Since you are working with a dashboard and require calling multiple endpoints to get summary, putting that workload on a (or multiple) backend api endpoint to minimize the number of calls would be helpful. The api endpoint would be responsible for aggregating the summaries using Promise.all (assuming a javascript backend). This has its own drawback of waiting for all responses to complete, which is why I said multiple endpoints. It can be improved with caching and NextJS Revalidation. The advantage of that is reduced network calls.
